# Using remote desktop client mac->pc

Tags: macos, windows-xp, remote-access

I am trying to remote log in to a PC using [Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24596)
[image]

The windows PC is configured in the system preferences to enable remote connection, but each time I attempt to connect using my Mac I get the same error.

[image]

Has anyone successfully used this?

-Update-
[image]

the firewall is definitely disabled on the pc.

[image]

and remote login is definitely enabled.

any ideas?

**CORRECTION**
This now works over the shared wireless network. If i test with the mac and pc connected to different wireless networks it does not work. What else needs to be appended to the IP address for the remote software can find the machine?

**FINALLY**
http://www.whatsmyip.org/
use this link to get your EXTERNAL IP. this is what you need to use to accomplish this.
Thank you so much everyone for your patience!!

Comment: You sure there's no firewall in the way? Try disabling all firewalls first to check.

Comment: Are they in the same LAN?

Comment: they are right now, but overall they will not be. i will be using wifi to connect.

Comment: Does RDC work win you do Win->Win?

Comment: @jasonm: Why would you filter a *local IP*? You would be better of filtering your computer name from the other image because it gives a lot away if you feel targeted, in case you would like to do so flag the post for a moderator (because we can still see older edits).

Comment: yeah i am obviously not that experienced with this stuff yet!

Comment: Jason, what do you mean by WAN? WAN typically a network that covers several geographic locations (different office branches) are you trying to say you are connecting via WiFi? Or, are you saying you are trying to connect from a different location like a friends house or coffee shop?

Comment: i used the term WAN incorreclty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default port that the Windows Remote Desktop Client uses is 3389.  So, first, when you attempt to connect, add that port to the IP address.  192.168.x.x:3389

As has been mentioned, make sure the Windows Firewall is set to allow RDC connections and/or connections on port 3389.  Check to ensure there is no firewall installed on the Mac that is blocking activity on 3389.

Check your router as well.  Feel free to forward all traffic on port 3389 to the specific IP address of the Windows PC.  Go that extra step and assign a static internal IP address to the Windows PC MAC address in the reserved DHCP table.

Comment: thanks i tried the 3389 but i am still getting the same issue. do i need to be logged off on the windows machine i am trying to connect to from the mac?

Comment: @jasonm: No, RDP will by default automatically log off the current user.

Comment: @jasonm you say that this works over shared wireless, but not over *different* wireless networks.  What exactly do you mean by that?  Do you mean two wireless routers connected via an ethernet cable?  Or do you mean if you leave the house and try to RDC into the computer, you can't?  If you mean that you are trying to connect from outside of your shared LAN, then you need to do three things.  You need to make sure the Win PC has a static internal IP.  You need to have port 3389 forwarded to that IP at the router, and you need to connect to your EXTERNAL IP address with the Mac.